# Is it possible to run Ethminer on more than one GPU of different types

Tags: mining, gpu

I have a system with a GTX 1080Ti which I am experimenting mining with. I have a couple of GTX 970 cards floating around that I haven't got round to selling yet.

If I installed a GTX 970 card alongside my 1080Ti would I be able to mine on both at the same time?

Would I run into any issues with other programs or games if I had 2 different chipsets of GPU installed?

Thanks